# DB2, openjpa, @ManyToMany: error "expected type varchar but column type is blob"

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Getting the following error:

```
<openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "com.qbe.asia.ebusiness.admin.intermediary.Intermediary.employees<element:class com.qbe.asia.ebusiness.admin.intermediary.Employee>" declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "varchar".  Column details:
Full Name: TINT_STAFF.STAFF_ID
Type: blob
Size: 0
Default: null
Not Null: false
```

Intermediary,java

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "TINTERMEDIARY" )
public class Intermediary {

    @Id
    @Column(name="INTERMEDIARY_ID")
    private String intermediaryId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="TINT_STAFF",
        joinColumns = {
                  @JoinColumn(name = "INTERMEDIARY_ID"),
                  @JoinColumn(name = "STAFF_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                  @JoinColumn(name = "STAFF_ID""), 
                  @JoinColumn(name = "INTERMEDIARY_ID")})
    private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

Employee.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="TSTAFFMEMBER")
 public class Employee {

   @Id
   @Column(name="STAFF_ID")
   private String employeeId;

   @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "employees")
   private List<Intermediary> intermediaries;
 }
```

TINT_STAFF table

```
CREATE TABLE TINT_STAFF
(
    INTERMEDIARY_ID CHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    STAFF_ID CHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( INTERMEDIARY_ID, STAFF_ID )
);
```

And all id fields are CHAR(19) in other tables too.

Without association mapping works like a charm but as soon as I add the ManyToMany through TINT_STAFF table, it says column is a blob.. but it isn't. Why?

Updated:

Test that fails

```
@Autowired
IntermediaryDaoJpaImpl dao; //this works fine

@Test
public void getIntermediariesTest() {
    List<Intermediary> intermediaries = dao.getIntermediaries();
    for(Intermediary intermediary : intermediaries) {
        System.out.println("Employees: "+intermediary.getEmployees());
        assert intermediary.getEmployees() != null; 
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager; //this works

public List<Intermediary> getIntermediaries() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select o FROM Intermediary o");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/Datasource</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.qbe.asia.ebusiness.admin.intermediary.Intermediary</class>
        <class>com.qbe.asia.ebusiness.admin.intermediary.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2(batchLimit=0)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `@JoinTable` annotation to:

```
@JoinTable(name="TINT_STAFF",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INTERMEDIARY_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STAFF_ID""))
```

Probably you wanted to do something like that.

Comment: This sets employees to null with lazy fetch. With eager fetch it throws <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
FailedObject: select o FROM Intermediary o [java.lang.String]. [.....................] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.setInverseRelation(JDBCStoreManager.java:453)
 at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:413)

Comment: Same from the other end, null if lazy, if eager: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
FailedObject: select o FROM Employee o [java.lang.String]

Comment: It's a really simple relationship and it should work as expected, maybe you have something wrong with JPA configuration. When this exception is raised? Do you have some test code?

Comment: Exactly, as close to a textbook example as it gets. Yet it doesn't work. Added test, dao and persistence.xml code.